# Ruby ReGex Split at nth new line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this text:

```
str = "

This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
This is line 6.
This is line 7.
This is line 8.
This is line 9.
This is line 10."
```

In ruby I want to make an array of this text split by every 3rd new line.

```
arr = ["This is line 1.
    This is line 2.
    This is line 3.",

    "This is line 4.
    This is line 5.
    This is line 6.",

    "This is line 7.
    This is line 8.
    This is line 9.",

    "This is line 10."]
```

I can't get a correct RegEx rule to accomplish it.
So far I got

```
arr = str.split(/((?:.*)\n){3}/)
```

Unfortunately it matches not only 3rd line's \n but also the text before it. It would be great if somehow i could exclude that text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be as fancy as an regexp, but perhaps it is easier to understand...

```
string.split(/\n/).each_slice(3).map { |slice| slice.join("\n") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex :

```
(\n?[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*)
```

http://rubular.com/r/f2at0uX3D2

Note that instead of `.*` you need to use `[^\n]*` that will match any thing except newline.

Or more precise :

```
((?:[^\n]*\n){3})
```

Comment: And what about every 10 000 th line? Because I used 3 only for simplicity here.

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:[^\n]*\n){3})
```

Split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/14

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is almost correct.. just include correct capture groups:

```
((?:(?:.*)\n){3})
^ ^^            ^
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nX6cI0/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups

```
((?:(?:.*)\n){3})|(.*)$
```

Groups `1` and `2` will return what you need

[DEMO - Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uO5gV7/2)
[DEMO - Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/TSBBltCUBw)